# TYPO3 How can I get all validation errors before being output to view

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 own extension validation of form inputs is done before control is handed over to the `controller` action. How can I get to work on the validation errors before being handed over to `view`?

Comment: So you want to do the validation inside the controller?

Comment: @Rustyjim Not really. What I would like to do is 'intercept' error messages and work on them in controller before calling `view`

Comment: could you solve it? if so could you answer so i can see how you did solved it because searching also how to get all erros before outputing it to the view where vuejs handles then this errors to show them instead of parsley or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there should be no reason to do this. However, what you could do is to override the errorAction() method (which is inherited from  AbstractActionController) in your controller. There, you can get the validationResults like this:

```
$validationResults = $this->arguments->getValidationResults()
```

Then you can fiddle with them before they are bound to the current request object:

```
    $originalRequest = clone $this->request;
    $this->request->setOriginalRequest($originalRequest);
    $this->request->setOriginalRequestMappingResults($validationResults);
```